# Not a constructor error when importing packages for React Typescript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I work on a project that uses React with Typescript. I am trying to import a package and the error I get when I run the file is that the package has no constructor.

I have noticed that error in many packages and I would like to ask if there is a way to make them work instead of trying to find another package that has a constructor.

The package that i am testing right now is called **jsPDF**

> Uncaught TypeError: jspdf_1.default is not a constructor

My code is

```
import jsPDF from 'jspdf';

export default class DataModelPage extends React.Component<any, any> {

public render(){
    let doc = new jsPDF()

    doc.text('Hello world!', 10, 10)
    doc.save('a4.pdf')

    return (
        <div>...</div>
    )
}
```

Comment: Can you share your import statement? I'm wondering if you are trying to import defaults where the package has no default export?

Comment: @Fenton actually post that as an answer because the fix is to `import * as jsPDF` instead of `import jsPDF`!

Comment: I guess this depends on the contents of the jsPDF module, or perhaps you just need the typescript definition file for jsPDF

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When importing using the following syntax, you are relying on there being a default export in the module:

```
import jsPDF from 'jspdf';
```

In many cases there is no default export (I prefer things that way to be honest, as you get to be explicit about your dependencies) - so you need to import using either...

```
import * as jsPDF from 'jspdf';
```

Or...

```
import { justTheThingIWant } from 'jspdf';
```

(where justTheThingIWant is the name of the thing you want.

Answer (score 0):

Below code worked for me in angular 8 project.

```
import * as jsPDF from 'jspdf';
```

Additionally, if someone is trying to export primeNG table content to pdf in landscape mode then may help below codes:

Need to import below library.

```
import 'jspdf-autotable';
```

Use below lines of code in .ts file.

```
const doc = new jsPDF('l', 'mm', 'a4');    
doc.autoTable(this.exportColumns, data);    
doc.save(this.getFileName('.pdf'));
```

It may help someone.