# ng serve no longer works. Cannot find modules

Tags: angular, npm, npm-install

I added some npm packages last night in an effort to install a color picker. Today, I had to work on a laptop and pulled the repo down and ran npm install. I had some issues where I was first told that the node_modules/index.js file did not exist. I created an empty file there by that name. The code compiled and I got an error in the console of

```
Uncaught TypeError: AllHtmlEntities is not a constructor
    at Object../node_modules/webpack-dev-server/client/overlay.js (vendor.js:331033)
    at __webpack_require__ (runtime.js:85)
    at Object.<anonymous> (vendor.js:330846)
    at Object../node_modules/webpack-dev-server/client/index.js?http://0.0.0.0:0/sockjs-node&sockPath=/sockjs-node (vendor.js:331013)
    at __webpack_require__ (runtime.js:85)
    at Object.0 (main.js:42976)
    at __webpack_require__ (runtime.js:85)
    at checkDeferredModules (runtime.js:46)
    at Array.webpackJsonpCallback [as push] (runtime.js:33)
    at main.js:1
```

The code will not compile and I get the following error :

```
An unhandled exception occurred: Cannot find module './features/avif'
See "/private/var/folders/bm/gjfl16s959nfnzpchxpcv0s00000gp/T/ng-ihA5FD/angular-errors.log" for further details.
```

I have no idea what has happened here nor how to solve it.

Comment: looks similar: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46602927/not-a-constructor-error-when-importing-packages-for-react-typescript Does it help?

Comment: No, this is an issue with npm dependencies and not angular dependencies

Answer (score 0):

I remember something similar. Mostly it had something to do with the node or npm version that my system has set as default. Since then I use NVM (Node Version Manager) to handle this kind of issues.

see here: https://itnext.io/nvm-the-easiest-way-to-switch-node-js-environments-on-your-machine-in-a-flash-17babb7d5f1b